# Use exception for type mismatch in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I am implementing an IDictionary interface, which has parameter `object` for its `get` `set`.

```
object this [object key] { get; set; }
```

I want to enforce the key to be type of string, so in my code I do:

```
(if key.GetType() != typeof(string)) {
    //
}
```

I want to throw an exception when this happen. However I don't know what the most appropriate exception to use in this case. The closest one I can find is **TypeInitializationException** and **ArgumentException**. However, it is stated in this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229007%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): "Do throw System.ArgumentException or one of its subtypes if bad arguments are passed to a member", which makes me wonder if mine is the right use case for it.

What should I use my case? Should I use **Assert** instead of throwing Exception?

Comment: You can also implement your own exception if you'd like.

Comment: Your code will through a null pointer exception if you pass it null. If you use `!(key is string)`, you'll get whatever exception you throw inside the `if`.

Comment: Why not enforce the key to be a string in the type argument? e.g. IDictionary<string, T>

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh, would you mind giving me an example on how to enforce it in type argument? This is something I haven't thought about.

Comment: @bizi if you use the generic IDictionary you could use: class YourDictionary<V> : IDictionary<string, V>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ArgumentException` is the correct exception. The entire BCL uses it and so should you. `TypeInitializationException` does not fit at all. It has one use case only: a throwing static ctor.

That said, if you are not producing a library (just internal code) you can deviate from that convention if there is a good reason. If you want to use a `Debug.Assert` or some alternative, feel free to do it.

Comment: I think Matthew's comment is the best approach for what I am doing. However, this answer is the best match for the title of my question, I will mark this as answer to make it easier for people come here through search.

Answer (score 3):

First I think, the best solution is Mathhew's; Why you just not using the Generic dictionary of type string.

If you need to apply the other approach than Code Contracts is the best way to do that.

Example:
Contract.Requires(key is string);
etc. 
Assert is not suitable for this problem but ArgumentException can be applied.

Thanks